# How to register entity listener without using orm.xml in spring with java config?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this **orm.xml** file to register **AuditingEntityListener** globally for all entities.

```
// orm.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener
                    class="org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener" />
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

I understand we could use abstract mapped superclass with annotations. But I don't want my entity classes to be extending class. I'm modeling entity classes using kotlin data classes.

```
@MappedSuperClass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {}
```

Is there a way to register this entity listener without using orm.xml with java config?

Answer (score 0):

You can register EntityListeners on the EventListenerRegistry.

Just unwrap the SessoinFactory like:

```
 SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap( 
 SessionFactoryImplementor.class );
 sessionFactory
     .getServiceRegistry()
     .getService( EventListenerRegistry.class )
     .prependListeners( EventType.LOAD, new SecuredLoadEntityListener() );
```